# Error freeing memory after sorting the array pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

How will I be able to maintain the position of the allocated memory so that freeing memory of a sorted array will not be affected?

I am trying to sort the pointer array. I noticed that when I free the **words** double pointer variable it will give an error **HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED**. The input I entered was "f ff 1".

Unsorted: f ff 1
Sorted: 1 f ff

I noticed that when I sort and free it will expect the same order which is "f ff 1". That is why I got some error.

Any suggestion on how will be able to free the sorted pointer array?

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
    A logical type
 */
typedef enum {
    false,
    true,
} bool;

/*
    Bubble Sort
*/
void sort(char *myargv[], int n)
{
    int i, j, cmp;
    char tmp[256];

    if (n <= 1)
        return; // Already sorted

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
        {
            cmp = strcmp(myargv[j], myargv[j+1]);

            if (cmp > 0)
            {
                strcpy(tmp, myargv[j+1]);
                strcpy(myargv[j+1], myargv[j]);
                strcpy(myargv[j], tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}

void printArray(char *myargv[], int myargc)
{
    int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < myargc; ++i) {
            printf("myargc[%d]: %s\n",i , myargv[i]);
        }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char text[256];
    char *myargv[256];
    char *myargvTemp[256];
    int myargc;
    int i = 0;
    int text_len;
    bool new_word = false;
    int index_start_word = 0;
    char **words;                                         //this will store the found word
    int count = 0;

    while(1){
        printf( "Enter text:\n");
        gets(text);                                       //get the input
        text_len = strlen(text);                          //get the length of the text
        words = (char **) malloc(text_len * sizeof(char));

        if (strlen(text) == 0 || text == '\0') exit(0);  //exit if text is empty


        for (i = 0; i < text_len ; ++i){
            if(text[i] != ' '){                          //if not space
                if(new_word == false){
                    new_word = true;
                    index_start_word = i;
                }
            } else {
                if (new_word == true) {
                    words[count] = (char *)malloc(i - index_start_word * sizeof(char)+1);   //memory allocation
                    strncpy(words[count], text + index_start_word, i - index_start_word);
                    words[count][i - index_start_word] = '\0';                              //place NULL after the word so no garbage
                    myargv[count] = words[count];
                    new_word = false;
                    count++;
                }

            }

            if (new_word == true && i == text_len-1){
                words[count] = (char *)malloc(i - index_start_word * sizeof(char)+2);
                strncpy(words[count], text + index_start_word, (i+1) - index_start_word);
                words[count][(i+1) - index_start_word] = '\0';
                myargv[count] = words[count];
                new_word = false;
                count++;
            }
        } 

        myargc = count;
        //not sorted
        printf("myargc is: %d\n", myargc);           
        printArray(myargv, myargc);

        //sorting happen
        sort(&myargv, myargc);
        printf("-----sorted-----\n");
        printf("myargc is: %d\n", myargc);
        printArray(myargv, myargc);

        memset(myargv, 0, 255);                         
        count = 0;
        i = 0; 


        //free the memory of words
        for (i=0; i<myargc; ++i) {
                free(words[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add `#include <string.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`, switch on compiler warnings and read them.

Comment: I got what you mean I figured out it should be sort(myargv, myargc); .However the freeing error still exist by changing that.

Comment: Probably you are not allocating enough memory wit `malloc`. Check that you never write beyond a memory block returned by malloc.

Comment: Try `words = (char **) malloc(text_len * sizeof(char *))`

Comment: That's the strangest way I've seen of defining `bool`. If you can use C99 or above, you should use `<stdbool.h>`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz - I think I gave it enough allocation, I tried not to perform sorting and freeing works well. However, after sorting the pointer array and free error occured.

Comment: @AnthonyGladiator well, then you know where to look for your problem.

Comment: Sidenote: comments such as `//memory allocation` on a line with `malloc` or `//get the length of the text` on a line with `strlen` are pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 problems in your code:

- you do not allocate enough space for the array of pointers: change the `words = (char **) malloc(text_len * sizeof(char));` to this:

  ```
  words = malloc(text_len * sizeof(char *));
  ```

  This allocation is actually incorrect: you should compute the number of words and allocate the correct size for the pointer array, or use a fixed size array.
- you swap the contents of the strings instead of swapping the pointers.  This is incorrect as the various strings do not have the same lengths.

Here is a corrected version of the sorting function:

```
void sort(char *myargv[], int n) {
    int i, j, cmp;

    if (n <= 1)
        return; // Already sorted

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
            cmp = strcmp(myargv[j], myargv[j+1]);
            if (cmp > 0) {
                char *tmp = myargv[j+1];
                myargv[j+1] = myargv[j];
                myargv[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want words to hold pointers to char so you need to change

```
 words = (char **) malloc(text_len * sizeof(char)); //will allocate array of single byte
```

to

```
 words = (char **) malloc(text_len * sizeof(char *));// will allocate array of pointers
```

Comment: Thanks for that but still i got error on freeing the memory